# How to map entities to existing graph?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I got a graph which is described by the following Cypher expression:

```
CREATE
(BMW:Brand {name: "BMW", country: "Germany"}),
(X3:Model {name: "X3", acceleration: 7.1, maxSpeed: 227.5, displacement: 1997, consumption: 6}),
(lastGen:Generation {from: 2013}),
(xDrive20i:Modification {name: "xDrive20i", maxSpeed: 210, acceleration: 8.3, consumption: 7.9}),
(X3)-[:MODEL_OF]->(BMW),
(BMW)-[:MODEL]->(X3),
(lastGen)-[:GENERATION_OF]->(X3),
(X3)-[:GENERATION]->(lastGen),
(xDrive20i)-[:MODIFICATION_OF]->(X3),
(X3)-[:MODIFICATION]->(xDrive20i),
(lastGen)-[:MODIFICATION]->(xDrive20i),
(xDrive20i)-[:MODIFICATION_OF]->(lastGen);
```

I described a java class matching to `Brand`'s data structure:

```
@NodeEntity
@TypeAlias("Brand")
public class Brand {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Indexed(indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT, indexName = "brand_name")
    private String name;

    private String origin;

    private String owner;

    @RelatedTo(type = "MODEL", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Model> models;

    //getters and setters are ommited
}
```

and repository:

```
public interface BrandRepository extends GraphRepository<Brand>{

    //method's signatures are ommited

}
```

When I call `brandRepository.count()` it returns 1 as I expect. But if I call `brandRepository.getOne(2249L)` I get an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary SDN label exists .. (i.e one with starting with __TYPE__)
```

As I understand reading `LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy` source, a node has to have at least one label with `__TYPE__` prefix.

How do I map the entity to the graph given that I may not change the graph structure?

I wouldn't mind implementing my own custom `LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy` if there is no other way. But in this case could somebody let me know why it is implemented this way (I think it is not accidentally) and how should I bind custom solution to `spring-data-neo4j` use it?

I use neo4j-2.0.0-M06 and spring-data-neo4j-3.0.0.M1.

Comment: I didn't find an answer to my question but I approached to my problem another way. I changed to Ruby technologies and used [neo4j](https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j) gem. It acts exactly as I expect at least not adding meta-information to my data.

Answer (score 2):

SDN adds additional metadata to your graph when you store entities, that metadata is missing in your case.

You can try to add that metadata yourself by calling

```
neo4jTemplate.postEntityCreation(node, Brand.class);
```

but that for instance doesn't index your name field (manual legacy index).

Comment: Thank you for reply. This approach gives me a chance of getting entities from data which has been imported using Cypher expression but price of it is metadata changes the data. I have no objections against metadata, I'm against poluting user-space with metadata.

Comment: Can I avoid presence the metadata in the data by any means? And how that may cause troubles in the future?

Comment: @RandomFreeman yes, don't use SDN, use [neo4j](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded.html). The metadata isn't pollution if you need SDN, because SDN needs the metadata, therefore you need the metadata. it's pollution if you *don't* need (and/or want) anything SDN gives you, and in that case, if this "pollution problem" is that important to you, you should look into using the java API directly.

Comment: @Micheal Hunger how about when you want to delete a node with the repo.deleteAll()? I am getting the same error and it seems to come up abruptly even though all my nodes are created with SDN.